# Finding country information for Blackberry IP addresses

Tags: security, dns, ip

I do some IP security for members on a web site. One approach we use is to determine the country the connection is coming in on from a number of sources, ARIN/RIPE/LACNIC/APNIC/AFRINIC as well as a few other non standard registries.

However, I'm running into problems with connections coming in through RIM servers. Those servers located mostly in Canada and the UK serve as exit points for connections coming in from all over the world.

Ideally, I would like to know if there is a way to find out the originating countries of those connections. Is there perhaps an RIM or Blackberry service to which I can subscribe? A free service/database/website to get this info, or am I wasting my time?

Comment: Is this for HTTP? Maybe there will be some User-Agents set by the application that you can use to detrmine this. What is your website written in?

Comment: Yes, sorry, HTTP. Site is in PHP. I've gone over thousands of Blackberry useragent strings and none of them give any idea of what country that connection is coming in from. I can sometimes determine the mobile O/S from the useragent string, but no country info.

Comment: You could embed a JavaScript function on the page, so that the user runs a query on there device, and then that data is sent to your server. Or simply use a tool like google analytics.